# Is there a faster way to count all hashtags using Tweepy and Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I want to return all hashtags that match my search, but it is currently taking a very long time to return all the data. In a perfect world I would like to return data where hashtag matches my search query. Get the count of how many times it was mentioned, and then see who tweeted it. Currently just to count the hashtags within a day takes a long time. Here is my current code.

```
def main():
    consumer_key= 'key'
    consumer_secret= 'key'
    access_token= 'key'
    access_token_secret= 'key'
    auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    search_words = "#search"
    date_since = "2021-04-26"

    tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                  q=search_words,
                  lang="en",
                  fromDate=date_since).items()
                  
    count = 0
    for tweet in tweets:
        count = count + 1
        #print(tweet.text)
    print(count)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT: I found out it is sleeping on the Wait Rate limit. Is their anyay around the wait limit?

Comment: Twitter has rate limits for calls to the API to enable support for everyone. There is no way to make an unlimited number of calls to the Twitter API in a short period, no.

Comment: @AndyPiper Would setting the count to something like 10000 count as one request? I am not sure how many requests I can make or how to lower the request count

Comment: did you do a basic search to look at the Twitter API docs for this legacy endpoint? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets I literally typed “twitter search api” into google, it didn’t seem too complicated.

Comment: @AndyPiper Thanks I found it with that guidance.

Answer (score 0):

in current version of tweepy counts are done like this:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token="TWITTER_API_BEARER")

# Replace with your own search query
query = 'search -is:retweet'

counts = client.get_recent_tweets_count(query=query, granularity='day')

for count in counts.data:
    print(count)
```